# Paypal with invoice and order confirmation in android app

Tags: java, android, paypal, paypal-sandbox, invoice

I have to develop one shopping cart app and integrate `Paypal`. How can I set the `Paypal` payment invoice data?

**How can I add productname, quantity, price to Paypal payment invoice?**.

This is my code for product that is added to cart page:

```
public class SingleMenuItem extends Activity {
static final String KEY_TITLE = "Name";
static final String KEY_COST = "Price";
static final String KEY_TOTAL = "total";
static final String KEY_QTY = "qty";
static final String KEY_THUMB_URL = "Image";
private EditText edit_qty_code;
private TextView txt_total;
private TextView text_cost_code;
private double itemamount = 0;
private double itemquantity = 0;
String mTitle, mQty, mCost, mTotal;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.single);
Intent in = getIntent();
    String title = in.getStringExtra(KEY_TITLE);
    String thumb_url = in.getStringExtra(KEY_THUMB_URL);
    String cost = in.getStringExtra(KEY_COST);
    String total = in.getStringExtra(KEY_TOTAL);

    ImageLoader imageLoader = new ImageLoader(getApplicationContext());

    ImageView imgv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.single_thumb);
    final TextView txttitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.single_title);
    TextView txtheader = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.actionbar);
    text_cost_code = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.single_cost);
    edit_qty_code = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.single_qty);
    edit_qty_code.setText("1");
    txt_total = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.single_total);

    txttitle.setText(title);
    txtheader.setText(title);
    text_cost_code.setText(cost);
    txt_total.setText(total);
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(thumb_url, imgv);

    itemamount = Double.parseDouble(text_cost_code.getText().toString());

    txt_total.setText(Double.toString(itemamount));

    edit_qty_code.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (!edit_qty_code.getText().toString().equals("")
                    || !edit_qty_code.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                itemquantity = Double.parseDouble(edit_qty_code.getText()
                        .toString());
                itemamount = Double.parseDouble(text_cost_code.getText()
                        .toString());
                txt_total.setText(Double
                        .toString(itemquantity * itemamount));
            } else {
                txt_total.setText("0.00");
            }
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });

    ImageButton mImgAddCart = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.img_add);
    mImgAddCart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            mTitle = txttitle.getText().toString();
            mCost = text_cost_code.getText().toString();
            mCost = mCost.replace("From ", "");
            mTotal = txt_total.getText().toString();
            mTotal = mTotal.replace("From ", "");
            mQty = edit_qty_code.getText().toString();

            if (Constants.mItem_Detail.size() <= 0) {
                HashMap<String, String> mTempObj = new HashMap<String, String>();
                mTempObj.put(KEY_TITLE, mTitle);
                mTempObj.put(KEY_QTY, mQty);
                mTempObj.put(KEY_COST, mCost);
                mTempObj.put(KEY_TOTAL, mTotal);

                Constants.mItem_Detail.add(mTempObj);

            } else {
                for (int i = 0; i < Constants.mItem_Detail.size(); i++) {
                    if (Constants.mItem_Detail.get(i).get(KEY_TITLE)
                            .equals(mTitle)) {
                        Constants.mItem_Detail.remove(i);


                        break;

                    } else {

                    }
                }

                HashMap<String, String> mTempObj = new HashMap<String, String>();
                mTempObj.put(KEY_TITLE, mTitle);
                mTempObj.put(KEY_QTY, mQty);
                mTempObj.put(KEY_COST, mCost);
                mTempObj.put(KEY_TOTAL, mTotal);

                Constants.mItem_Detail.add(mTempObj);
            }

            AlertDialog.Builder alertdialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    SingleMenuItem.this);
            alertdialog.setTitle(getResources()
                    .getString(R.string.app_name));
            alertdialog.setMessage("Add in ViewCart");

            alertdialog.setPositiveButton("OK",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int which) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            //finish();
                            return;
                        }
                    });

            alertdialog.show();

        }
    });

    ImageButton mImgViewCart = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.img_view);
    mImgViewCart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent mInViewCart = new Intent(SingleMenuItem.this,
                    ViewCartActivity.class);
            startActivity(mInViewCart);
        }
    });
```

This is code for product is added to cart:

```
ListView mLstView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    TextView mTxtViewGrandTotal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mTxtViewGrandTotalValue);
    Button mBtnSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mBtnSubmit);

    ViewCartAdapter mViewCartAdpt = new ViewCartAdapter(
            ViewCartActivity.this);

    mLstView1.setAdapter(mViewCartAdpt);

    if (Constants.mItem_Detail.size() > 0) {
        Double mGTotal = Double.parseDouble(Constants.mItem_Detail.get(0)
                .get(SingleMenuItem.KEY_TOTAL));
        for (int i = 1; i < Constants.mItem_Detail.size(); i++) {
            mGTotal = mGTotal
                    + Double.parseDouble(Constants.mItem_Detail.get(i).get(
                            SingleMenuItem.KEY_TOTAL));
        }

        mGrandTotal = String.valueOf(mGTotal);
        mTxtViewGrandTotal.setText("$" + mGrandTotal);
    }

    mBtnSubmit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CustomerLogin.class);
                startActivity(i);

        }
    });
```

This is my paypalintegrationactivity:

```
public class PayPalIntegrationActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
private PayPal mPayPal;
private CheckoutButton launchPayPalButton;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_pay_pal_integration);

    mPayPal=PayPal.initWithAppID(this,Constants.PAYPAL_APP_ID,PayPal.ENV_SANDBOX);

    initUI();

}


private void initUI() {

    launchPayPalButton = mPayPal.getCheckoutButton(this, 
            PayPal.BUTTON_278x43, CheckoutButton.TEXT_PAY);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);

    params.bottomMargin = 10;

    launchPayPalButton.setLayoutParams(params);
    launchPayPalButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    ((RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.main_layout)).addView(launchPayPalButton);
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    payWithPaypal();
}


private PayPalPayment payWithPaypal() {
    PayPalPayment newPayment = new PayPalPayment();
    BigDecimal bigDecimal=new BigDecimal(10);
    newPayment.setSubtotal(bigDecimal);
    newPayment.setCurrencyType(Currency.getInstance(Locale.US));
    newPayment.setRecipient("krishnaveni.veeman@mercuryminds.com");
    newPayment.setMerchantName("My Merchant");
    newPayment.setSubtotal(new BigDecimal(mTotal));
    newPayment.setPaymentType(PayPal.PAYMENT_TYPE_GOODS);
    Intent paypalIntent = PayPal.getInstance().checkout(newPayment, this);
    this.startActivityForResult(paypalIntent, 1);

    PayPalInvoiceData invoice = new PayPalInvoiceData();

        return newPayment;


}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch(resultCode) {
    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
        String payKey = 
        data.getStringExtra(PayPalActivity.EXTRA_PAY_KEY);
        Toast.makeText(this,"Payment Successful",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;
    case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
        Toast.makeText(this,"Payment Cancel",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;
    case PayPalActivity.RESULT_FAILURE:
        Toast.makeText(this,"Payment Failed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        String errorID = 
        data.getStringExtra(PayPalActivity.EXTRA_ERROR_ID);
        String errorMessage = 
                data.getStringExtra(PayPalActivity.EXTRA_ERROR_MESSAGE);
        break;
    }
```

Here how can i add productname to paypalpayment invoice.please help me.

Answer (score 0):

you can add paypalinvoice object to your project, then you can add details to that invoice,

```
try this code

PayPalInvoiceItem item1 = new PayPalInvoiceItem();
item1.setName("Pink Stuffed Bunny");
item1.setTotalPrice(new BigDecimal("6.00"));
item1.setQuantity(3);
invoice.getInvoiceItems().add(item1);
```

hope it will help to you.

Comment: How can we add the product dynamically.(i.e)How can we add the product from (SingleMenuItem)Product description page activity.this is statically.please refer my code and give me solution for this